# filter look up column value based on date ( if Data if = Today() ) Only Should Display in look up column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

[image: DATE= TOday() In list 1 , that value should be display in look up columns in list -B ,]

thanks in Advance i am using sharepoint on-permises

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using **InfoPath form**.

1. Customize **List 2 – CAB** list form via **InfoPath**.
2. Create a **Data Connection** to **List 1 – DRIVER** list as the data source. Select the **Date** field to ensure the **Date** (`Date Only field`) value from **List 1 – DRIVER** list can be received.

   [image]
3. Right-click the lookup field, and click **Drop-Down list Box properties…**.
4. Change to **Date source** to the new data source created above.
5. **Filter** Entries.

   a. Click “Select XPath” button next **Entries**

   b. Click **Filter Date…**

   c. Add a filter condition: `Date contains today() function`

   [image]
   [image]
6. **Publish** the form.

It will filer the values in the lookup field by `today()` date.

Answer (score 0):

Use REST to filter the results based on Today's date. (Update today val in required format)

```
var ListName='Test';
var date=new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;
var day = date.getDate().toString();
day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
var today  = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
var Query = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl+ "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + ListName + "')/Items?$select=DriverName,Cab&$filter=Date eq '" + today + "'";

    $.ajax({
        url: Query,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {


                var  jsonData= data.d;
                var i =0;
                var listItems="";
                for (i = 0; i < jsonData.results.length; i++)
                { listItems+= "<option value='" + jsonData.results[i].DriverName+ "'>" + jsonData.results[i].DriverName+ "</option>";
                }
            $("select[title^='Driver Name']").append(listItems);     

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr.status);

        }
    });
```